# Remove country form payment block

Tags: magento-2.1, onepage-checkout, billing-address, countries

I want to remove country from Checkout payment block. [image]

This was fill by knock js but i don't know how to remove this.

Comment: are you want to remove country from only dropdown of billing or remove from billing form also.

Comment: only from dropdown

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not 100% sure about this one, but I think the address in the dropdown is formatted via an admin settings.
You can go to `Stores->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration->Address Templates` and play with the values in there.
My money is on `Text one line`. Try removing `{{var country}}` from it and see if if works.

Comment: it is awasome Marius, I was going to override some classes.But you give a quick excellent solution

Comment: Really excellent solution without doing modification at code level :) @Marius